# What's the use case for using Atlantis and ArgoCD together?

Tags: devops, argocd, infrastructure-as-code, gitops, atlantis

I'm new to DevOps and I'm trying to understand how different tools fit together in a CI/CD pipeline. I've heard about Atlantis and ArgoCD, but I'm not sure how they work together.

As far as I understand, Atlantis is a tool for automating the workflow of merging and deploying infrastructure changes in pull requests. It integrates with your version control system and your infrastructure-as-code (IAC) tool of choice.

On the other hand, ArgoCD is a tool for automating the deployment and lifecycle management of Kubernetes applications. It can deploy applications based on GitOps principles, where the desired state of the cluster is defined in Git and continuously reconciled by ArgoCD.

My question is: what's the use case for using both Atlantis and ArgoCD together? Are there any benefits or drawbacks to doing so? For example, can Atlantis be used to automate the deployment of infrastructure changes to a Kubernetes cluster managed by ArgoCD? Or can ArgoCD be used to manage the deployment of Atlantis itself? can we just use atlantis and not argocd at all to manage all things (github resource, k8s cluster, etc)? any drawback to only use atlantis?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Atlantis is project used to extend the functionality of your CICD pipelines when using Terraform.

ArgoCD is a GitOps tool do deploy and sync applications to your Kubernetes cluster.

Since you can use Terraform to configure you ArgoCD cluster you can also use Atlantis with ArgoCD together. One scenario would be to let a developer create a new ArgoCD application with Terraform which then gets pushed to the Git repository. When the pull request gets created Atlantis will run the Terraform plan/apply for the new resources and populate the changes to ArgoCD.

I think using ArgoCD and Atlantis in your workflow is only helpful until bootstrapping an ApplicationSet for ArgoCD, because with the ApplicationSet you will create new Applications directly from Git.